# Combining mean differences in regressors and significant prediction and moderation in multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, interaction, group-differences, regression-strategies

I am analyzing a survey about career choices with an eye toward demonstrating *sex differences* in:

1) the means for factors that might be related to career choice (e.g., differences by sex in relationship with academic advisors), and,

2) the efficacy of those same factors in predicting interest in different career types (e.g., whether there is a significant interaction between sex and advisor relationship in predicting reported interest in academic careers).

I have found both types of results, and will report them separately, but I am wondering whether there is some way to combine them to demonstrate an "overall" effect for sex in predicting career interest.

My current plan is to use the unstandardized coefficients from the multiple regression results and combine them with the group means, when appropriate, to come up with "estimates" of Y for each sex and compare those estimates.

An example using created numbers.

`2 predictors:
    - X1 = relationship with advisor (range 1-5, 1=very bad)
    - X2 = importance of autonomy in career choice (range 1-5, 1=not important)
1 outcome:
    - Y = interest in academic career (range 1-5, 1=no interest at all)`

Suppose that there are significant differences in X1 by Sex, M(male)=4.1, M(female)=3.5, but no significant differences in X2 by Sex M(all)=3.3.

Suppose further that in a multiple regression X1 significantly predicts Y directly, and the interaction of X2 and Sex significantly predicts Y (above and beyond main effects X2 and Sex). The results might look like this:

`DV=Interest in academic career
                Coeff                         Mean                   Score
                -----                         ----                   -----
Term        Male    Female      p        Male     Female        Male      Female
          ----------------    ----     -----------------      ------------------
Intercept        2.5          <.05                               2.5         2.5
X1              0.25          <.05        4.1        3.5    4.1*0.25    3.5*0.25
X2                 0            ns                                 0           0
Sex                0            ns                                 0           0
X1*Sex             0            ns                                 0           0
X2*Sex      0.10      0.25    <.05             3.3          3.3*0.10    3.3*0.25
                                                            ====================
                                                                3.86        4.20`

(The X2*Sex interaction has been split into separate coefficients already).

What I am doing in the last "column" is using the group means and regression coefficients to create predicted Ys for each *group*, 3.86 for males and 4.20 for females.

Suppose that the pooled SD for the DV is 0.5, and therefore the difference in predicted group scores (0.345) is d=0.69 SD.

What say ye? Is it crazy or meaningless or wrongheaded to do this? How would I phrase the finding?

aTdHvAaNnKcSe (yes, I am old school) :-)